# Count iterations in a loop

Tags: python-3.x

New to programming. How to count and print iterations(attempts) I had on guessing the random number?` Let's say, I guessed the number from 3-rd attempt.

```
import random
from time import sleep
str = ("Guess the number between 1 to 100")
print(str.center(80))
sleep(2)

number = random.randint(0, 100)
user_input = []

while user_input != number:
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input("\nEnter a number: "))
            if user_input > 100:
                print("You exceeded the input parameter, but anyways,")
            elif user_input < 0:
                print("You exceeded the input parameter, but anyways,")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Not valid")
    if number > user_input:
        print("The number is greater that that you entered ")
    elif number < user_input:
        print("The number is smaller than that you entered ")

else:
    print("Congratulation. You made it!")
```

Comment: Just add a counter `count = 0; while user_input != number: count += 1`

Comment: Thaaaaaaank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions being asked. First, how do you count the number of iterations? A simple way to do that is by creating a counter variable that increments (increases by 1) every time the `while` loop runs. Second, how do you print that number? Python has a number of ways to construct strings. One easy way is to simply add two strings together (i.e. concatenate them).

Here's an example:

```
counter = 0

while your_condition_here:
    counter += 1 # Same as counter = counter + 1
    ### Your code here ###

print('Number of iterations: ' + str(counter))
```

The value printed will be the number of times the `while` loop ran. However, you will have to explicitly convert anything that isn't already a string into a string for the concatenation to work.

You can also use formatted strings to construct your print message, which frees you from having to do the conversion to string explicitly, and may help with readability as well. Here is an example:

```
print('The while loop ran {} times'.format(counter))
```

Calling the `format` function on a string allows you replace each instance of `{}` within the string with an argument.

Edit: Changed to reassignment operator